# How to turn on sticky edges between monitors?

Tags: debian, gnome3

How to turn on sticky edges between monitors? I want to make some effort for moving a mouse between the monitors. Similar behavior was in unity ubuntu and windows. For example: https://youtu.be/722-sR1sYRg
I use debian 9 gnome 3. I can't find a solution.

Comment: Some additional info would help here: what have you tried? What is an example of what you want?

Comment: Do you mean windows snapping to the edge of each virtual desktop?  `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false` may help.